# Same username, same gravatar, different users

Tags: support, user-accounts, gravatar

When I first saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/466731/laptop-comes-out-of-hibernation/468184), I thought it was a bug as the gravatars looked identical and they had different reputation. Additionally, both of them seem to be the OP.

[image]

---

However, they are different users (I guess he registered twice?) and it is pretty much impossible to tell them apart (without a clickthrough).

My request: Is it possible to give users with the same names different gravatars (by default)?

Additionally, merge these two accounts.

Comment: Please post a link to that topic.

Comment: @DanielBeck done, forgot to do that earlier, sorry

Comment: Both accounts are unregistered. Either cleared the cookies or used another browser or computer, so the association is gone. Allowing users to post unregistered is a deliberate design decision for SE sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gravatars are based on email addresses. No matter what website you're on, if it supports gravatars and you enter your email address, *it just works!*

Adding e.g. Super User account ID or display name to the gravatar identifier (hash of email address) will only break custom gravatars for users registered with the service who have a custom image.

So if a user has multiple accounts and uses the same email address for these accounts, all of the accounts get the same gravatar (and there are [worse](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/78194/accounts-with-duplicate-email-and-20-reputation-in-each)). That's simply how it fundamentally works. It's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Not all instances of user stupidity or carelessness can or should be solved by increasing the complexity of the technology involved.

Comment: So he registered twice with the same e-mail address?

Comment: @soandos The user didn't register at all, just entered a display name and email address for each of the posts. A cookie retains that information to associate a computer/browser with the "unregistered account" on the site, but it seems the user changed computers, browsers, or cleared the cookies.